# How to create a sliding bar for buttons in my Android App like that of the Sliding bar in Evernote for Bold, Italics, Underline etc

Tags: android, android-layout, evernote

[Here is a link to the image of the Evernote app with the sliding bar at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkoxK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured an answer to my own question.
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button 1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button 2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button 3"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button 4"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button 5"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button 6"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```